# loose index search postgres with conditions

Tags: postgresql

For certain filtering sub conditions on a products table I want to find out the distinct categories of those filtered products (millions of products).

The clear way of doing it

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_id FROM "products" WHERE _conditions_
```

takes long to complete when there are a lot of rows involved (it's not really changing much to use `GROUP BY` instead)

According to https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan when there are only relatively small amount of different values on the distinct col (like is the case here with ~30 categories), the condition

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_id FROM "products"
```

can be restated as a recursive CTE

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   SELECT MIN(category_id) AS category_id FROM "products"
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT MIN(category_id) FROM "products" WHERE category_id > t.category_id)
   FROM t WHERE t.category_id IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT category_id FROM t WHERE category_id IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "products" WHERE category_id IS NULL);
```

That actually perfoms better in my use case (milisecons instead of seconds).
But it is without the conditions.

**How to add the '`WHERE _conditions_`' part properly to the recursive CTE?**

Comment: Huh. That's a clever trick. It also suggests that the optimiser is missing a trick, though there may be subtle semantic differences.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I guess better support for loose index scans in postgres would be really neat

Comment: There is a feature request for loose index scans in the query planner here: https://postgresql.uservoice.com/forums/21853-general/suggestions/8973760-loose-index-scans where one can pass votes for it

Comment: which means about nothing without someone keen to do the work or fund others to do it. That's the thing with independent open source projects. Telling that I didn't even know there was a "uservoice" section for PostgreSQL and haven't seen it mentioned anywhere before

Comment: Is it so much about it "being open source" - if you wish a feature for say MS SQL you also cannot know if the feauture would be implemented at one point..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   SELECT MIN(category_id) AS category_id FROM "products" WHERE _conditions_
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT MIN(category_id) FROM "products" WHERE category_id > t.category_id AND _conditions_ )
   FROM t WHERE t.category_id IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT category_id FROM t WHERE category_id IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "products" WHERE category_id IS NULL AND _conditions_);
```

Like this. There are three of that *conditions*.

Comment: This works with my data to use the indexes, although it's now in the low hundreds of ms range (which is okay concerning table size and conditions I guess)